# Material UI v4 AppBar Won't Change Theme

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have Appbar (in MUI v4)

```
<AppBar position="fixed" className={classes.appBar}>
  <Toolbar style={{ padding: 0 }}>
    <... />
  </Toolbar>
</AppBar>
```

on my page when I change the MUI Theme to Light, it's not changing from it's default color

```
import { MuiThemeProvider, createMuiTheme } from "@material-ui/core/styles";

const theme = createMuiTheme({
  palette: {
    type: "dark"
  }
});

ReactDOM.render(
  <MuiThemeProvider theme={theme}>
    <Index />
  </MuiThemeProvider>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

[image]

If I add this to the palette, then I get background black... I thought I could change overall palette when I change type from light to dark..?

```
primary: {
  main: "#000000"
}
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Note: This answer is for MUI v4

On https://material-ui.com/ if you change the theme from light to dark (using the lightbulb icon in the AppBar), you'll notice that the AppBar is unchanged.

The AppBar uses the primary color as the background color by default and the primary color doesn't change when switching from light to dark.

If you have an AppBar with `color="default"`, then it will change when switching from light to dark. You can see this on the Simple App Bar demo: https://material-ui.com/demos/app-bar/#simple-app-bar

Comment: To add to this if you actually want to change the AppBar's background color use an **override** in your theme:
`const theme = createMuiTheme({
  overrides: {
    MuiAppBar: {
      colorPrimary: {
        backgroundColor: "#FFC0CB" // Pink AppBar
      }
    }
  },
  palette: {
    type: "dark"
  }
});`

Comment: @user1972814 I wonder why people haven't thanked you much.

Comment: You are the man :) Thanks for your answer, it helps a lot

Answer (score 5):

Starting from MUI v5, to change the AppBar colour in dark mode, you need to use the `enableColorOnDark` prop. Also, if `color="default"` is used in v5, then the color won't change. It needs to be a value specified [here](https://mui.com/api/app-bar/).

Ref: https://mui.com/components/app-bar/#api

Comment: Thanks for this! Needed the v5 answer for this.

Answer (score 0):

Well , if you can add color as default to AppBar and then you can try to switch dark mode , it will works but AppBar will loose default blue color :

```
<AppBar position="static" color="default">
      <Toolbar>
        <Typography >Shanti Lal</Typography>
        <Switch checked={darkMode} onChange={() => setDarkMode(!darkMode)} />
      </Toolbar>
    </AppBar>
```

Comment: Isn't this the same as the already selected answer, just without references?

Answer (score 0):

```
const matteBlackTheme = createMuiTheme({
    overrides: {
      MuiAppBar: {
        colorPrimary: {
      backgroundColor: '#000000' // Override primary color for AppBar
    },
    colorDefault: {
      backgroundColor: '#000000' // Override default color for AppBar
    }
      }
    },
    palette: {
      type: 'dark',
      background: {
        paper: '#18191A' // Override color for paper surfaces
      }
    }
  });
```

Comment: PS: This is in Material UI V4