# Material-UI - AppBar backgroundColor doesn't change when set type: 'dark' in createMuiTheme

Tags: javascript, reactjs, themes, material-ui

When I switch theme by changing the value of `theme.palette.type` to `'dark'`, all white components changed its color to dark, but it's not the case for component like AppBar which has primary color of `#3f51b5` as the default.

I thought by setting the `theme.palette.type` to `'dark'` would change its color to the dark variant `theme.palette.primary.dark` (`#303f9f`) or maybe real dark color (`#212121`), but it doesn't. How to apply the dark theme to this component too?

```
const theme = createMuiTheme({
  palette: {
    type: 'dark',
    primary: {
      light: "#7986cb",
      main: "#3f51b5",
      dark: "#303f9f",
      contrastText: "#fff",
    },
});

const App = () => {
  return (
    <MuiThemeProvider theme={theme}>
      <AppBar />
    </MuiThemeProvider>
  );
}
```

Comment: Can you share some of your code so we can see what you do?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Material UI AppBar Won't Change Theme](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56224684/material-ui-appbar-wont-change-theme)

Comment: Ups I didn't know, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use color as **default**.

```js
const App = () => {
  return (
    <MuiThemeProvider theme={theme}>
      <AppBar color="default" />
    </MuiThemeProvider>
  );
}
```

**Note**: If you change your background paper color then you can use **inherit** color property.

```js
const darkTheme = createTheme({
    palette: {
        primary: {
            main: '#01bf71'
        },
        secondary: {
            main: '#fffff'
        },
        background: {
            default: '#000',
            paper: '#000'
        },
        type: 'dark',
        text: {
            primary: '#fff',
            secondary: '#fff'
        }
    }
});
```

Now use  `<AppBar color="inherit" />` this will make appbar background color as **#000**